# Migrate recursive checkbox of calendar from sharepoint 2007 to 2013 programatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, migration, sharepoint-calendar, events

I am trying to migrate SharePoint calendar from 2007 to 2013 programatically.

Here is my code.

```
using (ClientContext clientcontext = new ClientContext(targetURL))
{
    clientcontext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
    Web web = clientcontext.Web;
    Site site = clientcontext.Site;

    ListCreationInformation Listcreate = new ListCreationInformation();
    Listcreate.Title = "Calendar123";
    Listcreate.Description = "this is my test calendar";
    Listcreate.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.Events;
    List oList = web.Lists.Add(Listcreate);
    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

    List list = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Calendar123");
    ListItemCreationInformation Listitemcreate = new ListItemCreationInformation();
    ListItem item = list.AddItem(Listitemcreate);

    item["Title"] = "StandUP Call";
    item["Description"] = "StandUp call will be hold in Meeting discussion room no. 3";
    item["Location"] = "First Floor";
    item["EventDate"] = DateTime.Now; //Start Time
    item["EndDate"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
    item["Category"] = "Business";
    item["fAllDayEvent"] = true;
    item["fRecurrence"] = 1;

    item.Update();

    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

It creates an event in calendar but `item["fRecurrence"] = 1` is not working properly and getting below error.

> <--RENDERING FAILED-->

Because to work properly it also needs RecurrenceData and I don't know how to insert that using program.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [this URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms434156(v=office.14).aspx) for RecurrenceData schema and write a C# function to generate the schema based on parameters like

1. RecurrenceType Enum { Hourly, Daily, Monthly, Yearly}
2. FirstDayOfWeek Enum {Su, Mon, Tue, Web, Thu, Fri, Sat}
3. Frequency Integer
4. WindowEnd DateTime
5. RepeatForever Boolean
6. RepeatInstances Integer

And set it to the **RecurrenceData** field of the ListItem or you can set a static XML value to it like this:

```
    ....
    string recData = "<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><daily dayFrequency=\"1\" /></repeat><windowEnd>2012-02-26T01:00:00Z</windowEnd></rule></recurrence>";
    item["RecurrenceData"] = recData;
    ....
```